# Android: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android

Hi i am passing a few variables from my second activity to my main activity thus causing
an "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" error is there a way to fix the null error i am getting

here is my code from main activity which is the activity the variables are being passed to

```
            Intent Transport = getIntent();
    Bundle Reciever = Transport.getExtras();



    bChange = Reciever.getBoolean("Changed");

    if(bChange == true)
    {


    minV = Reciever.getInt("Min");
    maxV = Reciever.getInt("Max");
    minS = Reciever.getInt("MinS");
    value = Reciever.getBoolean("distanceM");
    bScroll = true;

    }
```

is there such a way to bypass this error or such called null value that i have seen in the other similar posts

here is my xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.audiovolumecontrol.VolumeControlMAIN"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity

        android:name=".com.example.audiovolumecontrol.Options"
        android:label="@string/options_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks help is appreciated

it seems that the null value is on

```
  Bundle Reciever = Transport.getExtras();
```

is there any way i can bypass it without deleting it

Comment: your class namr is .VolumeControlMAIN

Comment: oh man.  PLEASE name your variables such that they start with lowercase letters.  Especially if you're going to call it Reciever and are developing for Android.

Comment: it was a late night when i did it ill change it haha good point

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest name for the Options Activity is given as ".com.example.audiovolumecontrol.Options"

I'm guessing you don't want that first "."

Comment: yea i want that last but i want the variables from options to pass through to the main activity

Comment: i just would like to know how to pass my null error on  Bundle Reciever = Transport.getExtras(); part of my code

Comment: Step 1 is to name your Options Activity correctly.  Get rid of the "." in the manifest.  If that doesn't fix it then you more clearly need to explain what you are doing step by step and what results you are seeing

Comment: I have two activities " the main one = AA " and "options one = BB" the BB has variables that change which i want to parse into the AA but the AA is getting a Null value when fetching the extras from BB on startup because BB hasent changed its variables yet is there any way to bypass or use a if statement to get around this?

Comment: I got rid of the "." i was trying various things that i kept reading the error still persists

Comment: I'd have to see how you're adding the variables in the Options Activity

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're saying.  You don't want to be parsing return values in onCreate (if that is what you're doing).  Why don't you start the Options Activity using startActivityForResult.  Then pass back the info in your Bundle extras and populate AA in onActivityResult

Comment: would startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); fallunder the AA then the  onActivityResult  under the BB or visa versa? Thanks for the help its highly apreciated

Comment: do you prehaps have an example i could refrence to?

Comment: don't mean this in a harsh way but google is your friend.  The great thing about Android is that you'll find a lot of people trying to do the same thing you are.  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html  is a good place to start and as you get more questions, just search SO or Google.  Especially with the basics, you're in good company